# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que un formulario tenga campos requeridos cuando "required" no funciona?

Tags: html, jquery, html5, ajax

llevo un par de días intentando que un formulario que estoy haciendo para un proyecto de la U tenga campos requeridos pero la etiqueta el atributo "required" no funciona ¿podría haber un método alternativo?

Comparto el código del formulario

```
<form method="post">
<div class="col-sm-12 mt">
    <section>
        <label for="motel">Elige el motel</label>
        <select class="form-control  sel" id="motel" required="">
            <option value="0" selected>Selecciona una opción...</option>
            <option value="Ibiza">Ibiza</option>
            <option value="Carpe diem barrio abajo" >Carpe Diem Barrio Abajo</option>
            <option value="Carpe diem Chiquinquira" >Carpe Diem Chiquinquira</option>
            <option value="Cesar's Palace" >Cesar's Palace</option>
            <option value="El Faro" >El Faro</option>
            <option value="El Faraón" >El Faraón</option>
            <option value="Maracana" >Maracana</option>
        </select>
    </section>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-12 mt">
    <section>
        <label for="motel">Elige la Habitacion</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="habitacion" name="habitacion" required>
            <option value="0" selected>Selecciona una opción...</option>
        </select>
    </section>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-12 mt">
    <div class="input-field">
        <label for="date-start">Elige la fecha y la hora</label>
        <input type='text' id="FechayHora" class=' form-control' data-language='es' data-timepicker="true" placeholder="Seleccione una opción..." name="FechayHora" required="">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-12 mt">
    <section>
        <label for="decoracion">¿Deseas decoración?</label>
        <select class="form-control sel" id="decoracion" name="decoracion" required>
            <option value="0" selected>Selecciona una opción...</option>
            <option value="Si" >Si</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
        </select>
    </section>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-12 mt">
    <div class="input-field">
        <label for="mail">Correo Electrónico o Teléfono celular</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="mail" name="mail" placeholder="Escribe una opción..." required="" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-12 mt">
    <div class="input-field">
        <h5 for="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" name="checkbox" class="form-info" required="">
            Aceptas nuestros <a href="terminos-y-condiciones.html" target="_blank">Términos y Condiciones</a> y <a href="tratamiento-datos.html" target="_blank">Tratamiento de datos</a>
        </h5>
        <h5 class="form-info">* Solo podremos enviarte el código de reserva suministrando información veridica</h5>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" id="enviarForm">Enkámate</button>
</div>
```

Además de ello tiene el siguiente código Ajax

```
$(document).on("click","#enviarForm",function(){
  var parametros = {
  "motel" : $("#motel").val(),
  "FechayHora" : $("#FechayHora").val(),
  "decoracion" : $("#decoracion").val(),
  "mail" : $("#mail").val(),
  "checkbox" : $("#checkbox").val(),
  "habitacion" : $("#habitacion").val()
  };


        $.ajax({
            url: "reserva.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: parametros,
            success: function(data){
                $("#formulario").html('');
                $("#formulario").html("<fieldset style='background-color: transparent !important;'><div id='success_page'><h2 style='color: #ffffff !important;'>¡Gracias por Utilizar Kama!</h2><p style='color: #ffffff !important;'>De 30 a 40 minutos nos estaremos contactando contigo. Espera la confirmación de tu reserva y enkámate.</p></div></fieldset>");

            },
            error: function (xmlHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                MensajeError(textStatus);
            }
        });
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ejecuté tu código y ejecutando solo el `required` funciona, solo debes saber que en el valor por defecto del `select`, el `value` debe ser vacío, si no, tomará como que si tiene un valor ingresado.

Para que los atributos required se ejecuten el evento debe ser ejecutado por un submit y no por un click, es por eso que se cambia el botón de tipo button a tipo submit, ademas se le agrega un return false para que el formulario no se envie con metodo convencional sino por ajax.

```js
$(document).on("submit","#formulario",function(e){

e.preventDefault();

  var parametros = {
  "motel" : $("#motel").val(),
  "FechayHora" : $("#FechayHora").val(),
  "decoracion" : $("#decoracion").val(),
  "mail" : $("#mail").val(),
  "checkbox" : $("#checkbox").val(),
  "habitacion" : $("#habitacion").val()
  };


        $.ajax({
            url: "reserva.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: parametros,
            success: function(data){
                $("#formulario").html('');
                $("#formulario").html("<fieldset style='background-color: transparent !important;'><div id='success_page'><h2 style='color: #ffffff !important;'>¡Gracias por Utilizar Kama!</h2><p style='color: #ffffff !important;'>De 30 a 40 minutos nos estaremos contactando contigo. Espera la confirmación de tu reserva y enkámate.</p></div></fieldset>");

            },
            error: function (xmlHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                MensajeError(textStatus);
            }
        });

        return false;
})
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

<form method="post" action="#" id="formulario">
 <div class="col-sm-12 mt"> 
  <section>
   <label for="motel">Elige el motel</label>
   <select class="form-control  sel" id="motel" required>
    <option value="" selected>Selecciona una opción...</option>
    <option value="Ibiza">Ibiza</option>
    <option value="Carpe diem barrio abajo" >Carpe Diem Barrio Abajo</option>
    <option value="Carpe diem Chiquinquira" >Carpe Diem Chiquinquira</option>
    <option value="Cesar's Palace" >Cesar's Palace</option>
    <option value="El Faro" >El Faro</option>
    <option value="El Faraón" >El Faraón</option>
    <option value="Maracana" >Maracana</option>
   </select>
  </section>
 </div>
 <div class="col-sm-12 mt">
  <section>
   <label for="motel">Elige la Habitacion</label>
   <select class="form-control" id="habitacion" name="habitacion" required>
    <option value="" selected>Selecciona una opción...</option>
    <option value="101">habitacion 101</option>
    <option value="102">habitacion 102</option>
   </select>
  </section>
 </div>
 <div class="col-sm-12 mt">
  <div class="input-field">
   <label for="date-start">Elige la fecha y la hora</label>
   <input type='text' id="FechayHora" class=' form-control' data-language='es' data-timepicker="true" placeholder="Seleccione una opción..." name="FechayHora" required="">
  </div>
 </div>
<div class="col-sm-12 mt">
 <section>
    <label for="decoracion">¿Deseas decoración?</label>
    <select class="form-control sel" id="decoracion" name="decoracion" required>
      <option value="" selected>Selecciona una opción...</option>
      <option value="Si" >Si</option>
      <option value="No">No</option>
    </select>
  </section>
</div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 mt">
        <div class="input-field">
            <label for="mail">Correo Electrónico o Teléfono celular</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="mail" name="mail" placeholder="Escribe una opción..." required="" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 mt">
        <div class="input-field">
            <h5 for="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" name="checkbox" class="form-info" required="">
            Aceptas nuestros <a href="terminos-y-condiciones.html" target="_blank">Términos y Condiciones</a> y <a href="tratamiento-datos.html" target="_blank">Tratamiento de datos</a></h5>
            <h5 class="form-info">* Solo podremos enviarte el código de reserva suministrando información veridica</h5>
        </div>
    </div>
<div class="col-xs-12">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" id="enviarForm">Enkámate </button>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Al parecer olvidé mencionar que hay un código en ajax adicional que puede estar presentando prolema.

Comment: @RaulMontes las preguntas debes saberlas redactar **es importante que leas [ask]** para que puedas recibir las respuestas que esperas, en este caso según lo que preguntaste la solución fue colocar el value del option predeterminado como vacío tal y como lo explica Santiago en su respuesta, saludos !

Comment: Lamento haberlo pasado por alto, pero noté que el conflicto podría venir de ahí al ejecutar el código compartido y ver que si funcionaba ¿es posible hablar por otro medio y compartir un repositorio en github?

Comment: @RaulMontes Y aún con los ajustes de Santiago sigue sin funcionarte?

Comment: Lo del valor vacío ya lo había probado y no funcionó.

Comment: @RaulMontes entonces agrega tu código del ajax y edita tu pregunta con lo que realmente quieres lograr, debes explicarte muy bien.

Comment: Ya hice lo que me recomendaste.

Comment: @RaulMontes ya edite mi respuesta con el ultimo requerimiento que hiciste.

Comment: Voy a probar santiago, gracias.

Comment: @SantiagoRoldan me aparece el toolip que dice requerido pero también me sale el mensaje que aparece luego de enviar el formulario

Comment: @santiagoRoldan probé nuevamente tu solución y no me deja enviar el formulario con campos vacíos, lo cual es perfecto, pero no me muestra el mensaje luego de darle click al botón sino que recarga la pagina

Comment: @RaulMontes Acabo de editar la respuesta en base a lo que me dices, pruebalo.

Comment: @SantiagoRoldan al parecer funciona a la perfección, ¿es posible que el mensaje no se muestre sobre el mismo cuadro blanco sobre el cual está el formulario sino que sea transparente? podrías ingresar a test.kama.com.co para que veas un poco de que hablo

Comment: @RaulMontes si la respuesta fue la solución a tu pregunta te invito a que la marques como aceptada, si tienes nuevas preguntas te invito a que las crees, la función de los comentarios es para pedir aclaraciones cortas de una pregunta/respuesta no para generar nuevas preguntas o para socializar o bien podrían seguir hablando por medio del [chat], saludos a ambos.

Answer (score 1):

Con javascript una opcion seria asi ojala te sirva

```
function validar(){
 var elemento=document.getElementById("motel");
if(elemento.value==""){//validas el elemento
    alert("No has seleccionado un motel");//envias mensaje
Return false
}
//y asi para los demas
}
```

Se me olvidaba y en el form pones `onsubmit="validar()"` para llamar a la funcion así:

```
<form method="post" action="#" id="formulario"onsubmit="return validar()>
```

Comment: ¿En qué parte en concreto debo colocar el onsubmit="validar()"?

Comment: Aka un ejemplo <form onsubmit="validar()" >

Comment: voy a probar, gracias.

Comment: @Raul edite mi respuesta se me habian pasado algunas cosas

Comment: no fue posible hacer funcionar el código que me diste

Answer (score 1):

Si vas a colocar un "select" como required, el "option" por defecto debe venir sin valor (value="") ejemplo:

```
<select class="form-control" id="habitacion" name="habitacion" required>
    <option value="" selected>Selecciona una opción...</option>
    <option value="1">Uno</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

La sintaxis correcta es solo:

```
<select class="form-control" id="habitacion" name="habitacion" required>
```

Answer (score -1):

Debes colocarlo de esta forma, te hace falta `="requiered"`:

```
<select class="form-control" id="habitacion" name="habitacion" required="required">
    <option value="0" selected>Selecciona una opción...</option>
```

Espero te funcione, si no, me avisas...

Comment: Pasar el valor required al atributo required no es obligatoriamente necesario, saludos!

Comment: De acuerdo lo tendré en cuenta de ahora en adelante.  Gracias